# Xcode7.0にアップデートしたらWarningが出ます

Tags: xcode, xcode7

Xcodeを7.0にアップデートしたら、次のWarningが出ます。

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'
```

Warningを消すには、
どうすればいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

古いXCodeで作成したプロジェクトには、`FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS`が指定されています。

```
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = (
    "$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks",
    "$(inherited)",
);
```

この指定はもはや必要がないのですが（XCode6の途中にて仕様変更）、XCode7へ移行する際に引き継がれてしまいます。XCode7には当該のディレクトリがないので警告がでます。

対処法としては、

- `project.pbxproj`を直接エディタで書き換えて当該の記述を消す
- Targetを作り直す（プロジェクトに複雑な依存性がなければこの方法でもいいと思います）

があります。他にももっといい方法があるかもしれません。

---

`project.pbxproj`は、`YourProject.xcodeproj`ディレクトリ以下にあります。ただ`xcodeproj`はそのまま開こうとするとXCodeが起動するので、ディレクトリ以下を参照するには以下の手順で開く必要があります。

[image: project.pbxprojの開き方]